not able to upload my webmap made by qgis2web into my website domain
I am trying to upload my webmap i made using qgis2web into my website, but i couldnt. i tried to deploy it through netlify and i am able to do, but not through my domain. my web host is hostinger. can anyone please help?

Try using the file manager provided by your domain manager.
In your case you can find the guide for using the hostinger file manager here
https://www.hostinger.com/tutorials/how-to-use-hostinger-file-manager/
Create a folder in the home with the name "test" and inside this folder insert the files created by qgis2web, so there will be the index.html file and all the related folders.
Reach your site at https://www.mysite.com/test/
Website will show the web map.

thanks for your reply. i have done this procedure, but its not ready to deploy the web

I didn't understand what you mean. What problem do you encounter?
